# Vb.Net SQL Server Management Object(SMO) file not found error

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, smo

I have a Vb.Net Windows Forms application, which has a certain feature that enables the user to take backup of database from the front-end of the application. In the back-end, the SMO (SQL Server Management Object) has been used. The development PC of this application has Microsoft SQL Server 2005 installed, but my PC doesn't have SQL Server 2005, rather it has both SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012.

Whenever I try to run the application from my PC, I get the following error message:

[image: SMO Problem]

I tried to search for a solution in the internet, but was unable to find a specific one. Most solutions are related to the problem of 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo' or 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo', but as shown in the screenshot, the problem is related to 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum'.

So what is the actual reason behind this problem, and what is the exact solution? Is this problem related to the SQL Server version as I suspect?

Comment: have you tried to compare the gac between development pc and your own?

Comment: @Zohar What is 'gac'?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz(v=vs.110).aspx